# Sending E-Mail to Gmail - Is there formatting to exclude the body text from trailing the subject line?

Tags: gmail

When users receive email to their Gmail account, emails are listed with subject line, body text snippet, date.

Is there a way to exclude the body text from appearing after the subject line? Our email templates have navigational links at the top and these appear consistently and we are concerned they are unappealing to users.

Answer (score 4):

Add some `&nbsp;` before the navigation links

Answer (score 0):

The emails in the body text are not listed as links in the email snippet.

Snippet:

[image]

Email (with link at the beginning):

[image]

Edit: maybe my answer is not a solution to what you are asking, so here is another try.

The body snippet is made exclusively of plain text. If there are images before the first line of text, they are discarded. So is empty space. And links are stripped of the URL and left just as plain text as well. Moreover, if you somehow manage to make the snippet appear like empty space, you might get yourself an usability problem, in that the users, expecting some sort of body text, might consider the email empty/spam and thus disregard it. I think your best option would be either to move the respective links to a different part of the email or restyle them in order to make them “appealing”.